# Cannot get the array in json when I put the data in the state

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

I'm having trouble to get the data of array in JSON.
I send the json file by using node.js and the code is down below.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router(); // 라우터 분리

router.get("/api/hello", (req, res) => {
  // app 대신 router에 연결
  res.json({ express: "hello~" });
});

router.get("/api/beef", (req, res) => {
  res.json();
});

module.exports = router; // 모듈로 만드는 부분
```

And the data which I send with json is like this.

```
  {
    "test": "Beef data get Completed",
    "name": "beef",
    "data": [
      { "productName": "양지", "price": 20000 },
      { "productName": "갈비", "price": 30000 },
      { "productName": "등심", "price": 15000 }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then I get the data by using fetch, and save it in the **state**.
I get the right data which I want in the fetch function but when I try to get the data out of the fetch function I keep getting the error like *cannot get the property blahblahblah...*
And this is the code I did in the client.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const itemList = ["돼지고기", "소고기", "닭&오리", "Sale", "연락처"];

class Contents extends Component {
  state = {
    parsedJson : "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._callAPI()
      .then(parsedJson=>{
        console.log("In the fetch : ",parsedJson[0].data[0])
        this.setState({
          parsedJson
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isError: true
        });
      });
  }

  _callAPI = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`api/${this.props.curPage}`);
    const data = response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(data.message);

    return data;
  };

  render() {
    const stateData = this.state;
    console.log("In the render : ",stateData.parsedJson[0].data[0]) <- !!!!!!!!!!!! where error occur
    return (
      <>
        <RenderByItemList
          curPage={this.props.curPage}
          data={stateData.productData}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first render of your component, `parsedJson` is string, and the `stateData.parsedJson[0]` returns an empty string, and there is no `data` property on an empty string, so you get the error.

For solving this problem you have to write an if inside your render method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const itemList = ["돼지고기", "소고기", "닭&오리", "Sale", "연락처"];

class Contents extends Component {
  state = {
    parsedJson: [],
    error: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._callAPI()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          parsedJson: res[0].data, // here we set state the data array
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          error // here we set state occurred error
        });
      });
  }

  _callAPI = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`api/${this.props.curPage}`);
    const data = response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(data.message);

    return data;
  };

  render() {
    const { parsedJson, error } = this.state;

    if (parsedJson && parsedJson.length) {
      return <RenderByItemList
        curPage={this.props.curPage}
        data={parsedJson}
      />
    } else {
      return !!error || 'loading';
    }
  }
}
```

And also it's better to handle loading on your fetch action:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const itemList = ["돼지고기", "소고기", "닭&오리", "Sale", "연락처"];

class Contents extends Component {
  state = {
    parsedJson: [],
    error: null,
    loading: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    }, () => {
      this._callAPI()
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            parsedJson: res[0].data, // here we set state the data array
            loading: false,
            error: null,
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            error // here we set state occurred error
          });
        });
    })
  }

  _callAPI = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`api/${this.props.curPage}`);
    const data = response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(data.message);

    return data;
  };

  render() {
    const { parsedJson, error, loading } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return 'loading' // or write a Loading component and render it everywhere
    } else if (error) {
      return error // or write an Error component
    } else {
      return (
        <RenderByItemList
          curPage={this.props.curPage}
          data={parsedJson}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So do you mean I can't touch the data array outside of the componentDidMount function?

Comment: You can touch it when you are making setState. But when you don't have the property, you can't select it and you will face error

Comment: Do you still have trouble? Or you pass the challenge?

Comment: I passed it!! Thank you very much~ And the answer I asked with comment is like this that I can't touch the data array outside the setState function right?

Comment: If you change the state manually, you would mutate the state. So if you want to change any data that changes the UI, you have to use setState function